# Is there a way to set test coverage for tests (f.e. 95%) using cypress.io in TeamCity?

Tags: node.js, teamcity, cypress

We are using TeamCity to run cypress.io for our NodeJs application and some of the tests are failing due to timeouts. These timeouts seem based on latency to the database (AWS RDS) and vary from build-to-build.

What we would like to do is to try setting test coverage to a 95% success rate and see if this allows the build to continue.

There is an option in TeamCity to have build steps to run regardless if the previous steps failed, but we would like our tests to not run in this fashion.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up modifying the tests so that they would behave as expected in the new environment. We also decided to run the tests as they were built to run with a local Postgres database.

The significant issue we were dealing with was our Cypress tests were extremely fragile when moving to an RDS database. The tests were configured for a local dev environment with a local Postgres database and moving to RDS in the CI environment broke them.

My recommendation is for anyone setting up automated tests to make sure tests run in your CI environment as they do in their development, not to configure/edit your tests to pass in CI.

In other words, if your tests break in your CI environment, then they need to be fixed in the dev environment.